# WordPress Error While trying to access wp-admin page

Tags: wordpress

I inserted a couple of new themes, and they work fine; however, when I upgraded my WordPress to 3.3.1(I believe), and when I tried to access the admin page, I get the following error:

```
  Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 122880 bytes) in /home/beachhot/public_html/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php on line 88
```

Here is line 88 of the dashboard.php file:

```
         wp_add_dashboard_widget( 'dashboard_primary', $widget_options['dashboard_primary']['title'], 'wp_dashboard_primary', 'wp_dashboard_primary_control' );
```

I'm really stuck and have no clue to fix this. If there is no way to do this, then I might have to re-install wordpress.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Increase your allocated memory in wp-config.php or wherever you need it:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

In case PHP itself is running out of memory, you can increase that by modifying php.ini and restarting your web server.

```
memory_limit 256M
```

Answer (score 0):

A theme/plugin is trying to put a Dashboard widget of some sort in your wp-admin homepage, Not enough info to fix that here I'm afraid. Put WP into [debug mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug) and see if there are any other errors being caused.

Also, should be no need to reinstall WordPress, just disable/delete the offending themes/plugins and it *should* go away. Otherwise like Matt H said, you could increase your memory limit but I would not recommend it if you don't know the consequences.

Comment: the problem is that I cannot access my dashboard to deactivate my themes. I tried going into the server a delete the theme, and it gave me a blank page, which is fine. However, I still cannot get into the dashboard

Comment: Put debug mode on, you should get some errors instead of a blank page

Comment: I re-installed wordpress and now everything is fine! Thanks for the help. However, I going to try debug mode, so that I know how to do it next time. Thank you!